# Compare two text files and find matching lines

Tags: grep, awk, search, string

I have two files A and B. A looks like this (4 to 6 lines):

```
GAGA
CAGA
GGGT
TATT
```

file B is a really big file with thousands of lines, here is a short example:

```
AAATGTCAAGAGACAGAAATGTCAAGAGGGT
AAGGGGGTTTATAATCATAAATCAAAGAAAT
ATATACAGAAATGTCAAGAGACAGAAATGTC
TCAAGAGACAGAAATGTCAAGAGGGTCTATA
AAGAGGGTCTATAATCATAAATCAAAGAAAT
AAGAGGGTCTATAATCATAAATCAAAGAAAT
ATACAGAAATGTCAAAACAGAAATGTCAAGG
ATATACAGAATATACAGAAATGTCAAGTTAT
ACAGAATATACAGAAATGTCAAGTTATATAC
ATATACAGAAATGTCAAGAGACAGAAATGTC
TCAGAATATAGTATTCTATTATATACAGAAA
AATATAGTATTCTATTATATACAGAAATGTC
GAATATACAGAAATGTCAAGTTATATACAGA
TATACAGAATATAGTATTCTATTATATACAG
CAGAATATAGTATTCTATTATATACAGAATA
AGTTATATACAGAATATAGTATTCTATTATA
TACAGAATATAGTATTCTATTATATACAGAA
CAGAAATGTCAAGTTATATACAGAATATAGT
```

I need to search every string in file A in all the lines in file B, and recover the first 10 lines from file B that contain each string from A. I have tried grep and awk but not with good results. Thanks

Comment: If a line in B contains both strings in A, it will print two times?

Comment: What if the string falls at the end of a line? Something like `GA\nGA`?

Answer (score 5):

Since your patterns are only four to six lines, why not use them in an OR pattern? An example limiting to 10 matches that operates on a second file "bigDNA.txt":

```
grep -E 'GAGA|CAGA|GGGT|TATT' -m 10 bigDNA.txt
```

This will save you from manually typing the patterns from file `patt.txt`. It joins lines by `|` (append `|` to each line, remove newline, remove trailing `|`):

```
grep -E "$(sed 's#$#|#' patt.txt | tr -d '\n' | sed 's#|$##')" -m 10 bigDNA.txt
```

Comment: I forgot to mention file A change with time, is not the same every case. That is why I need something more "complex"

Comment: @Alejandro It doesn't matter if it changes periodically, the second command can handle that. If you need to do some pre-processing, that is still possible. E.g. to print the last word if a line matches `FOO`, you would use a subcommand like `$(awk '/FOO/{print $NF}/' patt.txt | sed 's#$#|#' | tr ...`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I am new at this. Where in the second command I should specify file A?

Comment: @Alejandro, if I understand correctly, file A would be patt.txt

Comment: Correct, `patt.txt` would be your "file A". `bigDNA.txt` is "file B".

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried iterating through "file A" with a `while` loop?

```
while read string
 do grep "$string" file-B | head -10
done < file-A
```

Or in one line:

```
while read string; do grep "$string" file-B | head -10; done < file-A
```

Comment: +1 but I think the question wanted 10 lines for EACH line, so head maybe goes inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working right. The only thing I noticed is if I run it, and then go a change the order of the strings inside file A (and save it), i get a weird result (more than ten lines, and the are not in order). Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you doing this while the loop is running in another terminal?

Comment: No, I just waited until it was done and then change file A, and run it again, in the same terminal window

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hopefully readable script.

FIRSTFILE contains 1 item per line (with no extra spaces, etc)
BIGFILE contains the big list that you want to match

```
awk -F, '
  BEGIN{
     regexp="__NOTMATCHING__"
     linematched=0
     while(( getline line<"FIRSTFILE") > 0 ) {
        nb_items[line]=0; #initialise a counter in items["...."]
        regexp=regexp"|"line  #we create a "egrep-like" regexp matching each item
     }

  }

#main : read each line. 
#           - save each matching lines. 
#           - and increment each corresponding counters. 
  {  if ( $0 ~ regexp ) {
        matchinglines[++linematched]=$0
        for ( item in nb_items ) {
           #for each matching item, we also increment that item s number
           if ( $0 ~ item ) { 
              nb_items[item]++ ; 
           }
        }
     }
  }

END  {  #at the end, we print all items which have nb_item[item]>=10
        for ( item in nb_items ) {
           if (nb_items[item] >= 10) {
              print "for this item:",item
              for (i;i<=linematched;i++) {
                 if ( matchinglines[i] ~ item ) {
                    print matchinglines[i] ; 
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
   ' BIGFILE
```

Comment: it cuold be optimized: each time you increment a matching nb_items: if **all** are above 10, you can stop reading BIGFILE and go to the END section!

Answer (score 1):

This will print the 1st 10 lines that match any of your strings:

```
grep -m 10 -Ff motifs sequence.fa
```

This one will read each motif and print the first ten lines mathcing it, so it will print 10 lines for each motif:

```
while read mot; do grep -m 10 "$mot" sequence.fa; done < motifs
```

---

However, that looks like a DNA sequence, which means that the line breaks are completely arbitrary and you can have matches like this:

> ACTG **GA** 
>   **GA**

With these approaches, the `GAGA` above will not count as a match and this is probably not what you want. Instead, I suggest you put everything in a single line before you search. Since you are asking for matching lines, I assume you want each of these motifs in their context. So, to do this properly, matching motifs that are split across newlines, first transform your file to [TBL](http://haldane.bu.edu/needle-doc/latest/seq-formats.html#tbl-file-format) format. I've been using the same little `awk` script written by a colleague (thanks Pep) for years:

```
#!/bin/sh
gawk '{
        if (substr($1,1,1)==">")
        if (NR>1)
                    printf "\n%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
        else 
            printf "%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
        else 
                printf "%s", $0
}END{printf "\n"}'  "$@"
```

Save the script above as `FastaToTbl` somewhere in your `$PATH` (`/usr/local/bin` for example) and make it executable (`chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/FastaToTbl`). Then, you can simply pipe FASTA format sequences and it will print out `.tbl` format, where the identifier and the sequence are all on the same line.

So, once you have `FastaToTbl` set up, you can run:

```
while read mot; 
do 
    FastaToTbl sequence.fa | grep -Po ".{10}$mot.{10}" | head -n 10 
done < motifs
```

The above will give you the 1st 10 matches for each pattern and will also match motifs that are split across newlines. It will also print the 10 characters on either side of the matched pattern, change the `{10}` to another number to control this behavior.